# How to scroll to a shortcode-generated anchor

Tags: shortcode

I'm stuck...

I have a shortcode in a WP page.
The PHP function in the shortcode does the following logic:

```
if (isset($_GET['some_id'])) { // Get single item
   Query MySQL table to get the item with the id='some_id'
   // Show item
   $html .= 'Some html';
   $html .= '<div id="div_id">blabla</div>'; // <-- Here is the problem zone
   return $html; 
   // All of the above works perfectly
   }
else { // Show list of items
   Query MySQL table to get list of items
   //Show list
        foreach ($results as $result)
            $html .= $result->titel.' <a href="'.esc_url( add_query_arg( 'some_id', $result->id, 'The URL of the current page' ) ).'">Get details</a>';
        return $html;
        }
```

This code does what it should do: The page first shows the list of items (b/c URL parameter some_id is not set).

Then, in the list, I click on "Get details". The very same page reloads (now the parameter "some_id" is set) and I get the corresponding output with the div id="blabla" somewhere.

However, I want the page to then scroll directly to the div id ="blabla", but I'm not able to make that work. I tried javascript, jquery, and also putting the #blabla in the URL (url/?some_id=3#blabla)... Nothing works...

Any hint/pointer greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Larry

Sorry, it was a dumb javascript error.... Please excuse the disturbance.

Comment: `<div id="div_id">` is this your code in production? ids need to be unique! If they are and each element has a unique id, using `#<id>` will work

Comment: Yes, this id is unique on the page. It doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the code you tried using fragments (`#`) in the question, from there on we can better help you

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean (I don't ask very often, so maybe I'm missing something)

Comment: downvoted and close voted as this has nothing which is specific to wordpress as the question is right now. If your id is `div_id` then #div_id will bring you there, otherwise it is either not unique or you have some JS bug somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a WordPress related question, but since it was simple I posted an answer for you.

You can scroll to your element by using jQuery. Check if the query var is set, if so, scroll to the element after the page has been loaded:

```
(function($){
    // Function to get the current query var
    function get_query_var(query) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        query = query.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + query + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    // Check if query var is set
    var myQuery = get_query_var('some_id');
    if ( myQuery ) {
        // Now do the scrolling
            $( 'html,body' ).animate({
                scrollTop: $("#div_id").scrollTop()
                },1000
            );
    }
})(jQuery);
```